# How to extend Angular NgZorro component?

Tags: angular, extendscript, ng-zorro-antd

I would like to extend NzCardComponent and add some additional functionalities in my UI and have my own tag like `<my-card></my-card>`.
I need to override HTML also. How to do this? Just extending class is not giving HTML data.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to extend? You can simply create a component, using any ng-zorro component you like in html and add your desired HTML code to it.